# How to write #define expressions with nested brackets in cython?

Tags: python-3.x, cython, openal-soft

C expression:

```
#define EFX_REVERB_PRESET_GENERIC \
    { 1.0000f, 1.0000f, 0.3162f, 0.8913f, 1.0000f, 1.4900f, 0.8300f, 1.0000f, 0.0500f, 0.0070f, { 0.0000f, 0.0000f, 0.0000f }, 1.2589f, 0.0110f, { 0.0000f, 0.0000f, 0.0000f }, 0.2500f, 0.0000f, 0.2500f, 0.0000f, 0.9943f, 5000.0000f, 250.0000f, 0.0000f, 0x1 }
```

I want to define this expression in the **.pxd file**.

I have to pass this expression as parameters to some C functions. So I **don't use it for Python**.

**Source**: OpenAL-Soft: https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft/blob/master/include/AL/efx-presets.h#L37

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth realising that not everything has a direct translation from C to Cython. In this case `EFX_REVERB_PRESET_GENERIC` can't really be defined using a type because it isn't a type - it's just a collection of brackets and numbers. These brackets and numbers are only valid in a small number of places:

```
 void other_func(WhateverTheStructIsCalled s);

 void func() {
     WhateverTheStructIsCalled s = EFX_REVERB_PRESET_GENERIC; // OK
     s = EFX_REVERB_PRESET_GENERIC; // wrong - not an initialization
     other_func(EFX_REVERB_PRESET_GENERIC); // also doesn't work
 }
```

Therefore it doesn't really fit into Cython's model so you can't wrap it directly.

What I'd do is write a small C wrapper yourself. You can do this with Cython's "inline C code" function:

```
cdef extern from *:
    """
    WhateverTheStructIsCalled get_EFX_REVERB_PRESET_GENERIC(void) {
        WhateverTheStructIsCalled s = EFX_REVERB_PRESET_GENERIC;
        return s;
    }
    """
    WhateverTheStructIsCalled get_EFX_REVERB_PRESET_GENERIC()
```

Then use `get_EFX_REVERB_PRESET_GENERIC()` to call this function and get the relevant initialized structure.